# Place a comma in a string before value in parenthesis

Tags: python, regex

I have a string of names that is comma delimited and some of the names have an abbreviation after such as the following:

```
"major league baseball, national football league (nfl), major league soccer" ...
```

I want to place a comma before the parenthesis (before any opening parenthesis) so I can use string split. I tried using the following regex but doesn't quite do what I want.

```
result = re.split(",()", result)
```

Comment: Does `s = s.replace("(", ",(")` work?

Comment: I think this initial way worked as well, I realized there's a problem with my string (for some reason there are commas just after all opening parenthesis) and causing behavior I didn't expect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `replace` instead of a regex:

```
In [1]: s = "major league baseball, national football league (nfl), major league soccer (mls)"

In [2]: s.replace('(', ',(').split(',')
Out[2]:
['major league baseball',
 ' national football league ',
 '(nfl)',
 ' major league soccer ',
 '(mls)']
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to do this before split:

```
result = result.replace(' (', ', ').replace(')', '')
#"major league baseball, national football league, nfl, major league soccer"
```

Comment: this will remove the parenthesis. Is that what the question is asking for?

Comment: Not quite asked for, but it is good thinking and I was going to do remove all parenthesis anyway